# How can I remove the oil from my homemade nut milk?

Tags: oil, fermentation

I am trying to use a homemade nut milk (made from blending nuts and water then squeezing through a cheesecloth) as the liquid base for makgeolli (a fermented rice wine). I do not want to the nut oils to turn rancid during the ferment so I want to remove them ahead of time. What are the best ways to do this?

1. Allow long settling time in the fridge. Skimming top
2. Freezing, then removing any solidified oils? I don't even know if pistachio oil would congeal at freezer temperature

I want to know if there are any other ideas

Comment: A fairly short settling time and a gravy/stock separating jug?

Comment: The "Chemistry" way to do this, would be to add something that would bind/dissolve or remove the oils from emulsion. I don't know that it would work in this context, but you could try adding some oil (cooking oil, perhaps rapeseed/canola?), shake, allow oil to separate (it would float on the top), then carefully remove the floating oil layer (or take out the bottom, milk layer, somehow - siphon?)

Comment: If you start out with whole nuts and then grind them, I'm not sure whether the oil in the nuts is separated at all from the other ingredients in the nuts (which you want to keep).